# How do I add a dark overlay the background:url(" ") image in CSS without affecting the text?

Tags: html, css

I wanted to **add a black overlay or tint and change the opacity of the image** **I put in url(" ") in CSS**, but I don't know how to target that without affecting the text. How could I do that in CSS?

[This is the code, result looks different on codepen.](https://codepen.io/admitdefeat/pen/gOpbMvr)

```
.intro {
padding-bottom: 30%;
background: url("https://c4.wallpaperflare.com/wallpaper/521/963/803/3d-maze-wallpaper-preview.jpg")
no-repeat;
```

}

[Here is an accurate version what of it looks like.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bu5LP.jpg)

Side note: In adobe Xd I just had a black background, put the image over it and set the opacity of the image to 10%.